# Speeding up Sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Postgresql table with about 50 million entries. Now i want to find two id's, by looking for the first time and the last time a timestamp appears, to give me a range of entries.

Finding the "first" id  takes about 100 milliseconds.

But finding the second id takes about 3 minutes.

Query for finding the first id

```sql
SELECT id 
FROM transactions 
WHERE "hashBlock" = 
    (SELECT hash 
    FROM blocks 
    WHERE n_time > 1262300400  
    ORDER BY id ASC
    LIMTI 1)
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMTI 1
```

Query for finding the second id

```sql
Select id 
FROM transactions 
WHERE "hashBlock" = 
    (SELECT hash 
    FROM blocks 
    WHERE n_time < 1306879200  
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMTI 1)
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMTI 1
```

I guess the longer runtime result in the query going from the first id until it find an id which satisfies the query and the second one starting at the last id.

Is there any way to speed up the second query?

Comment: What are your table definitions?  What indexes are defined?  Please show the output of EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) your query...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create the following indexes, if you don't have them already:

```
create index ix1 on transactions ("hashBlock", id);

create index ix2 on blocks (n_time, id, hash);
```